# Javascript foreach loop calls ajax several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach

So I am trying to create to do list with several boards. Each board have add item button. If I click add item button it opens modal where to insert task info. But if I click add item button several times  and then insert info to modal and press save ajax fires as many times i clicked add item button. How can I prevent from that?

```
var addNewItems = document.querySelectorAll("#addNewItem");
var addNewSubmits = document.querySelectorAll("#listItemSave");
addNewItems.forEach(function(addNewItem) {
  addNewItem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var newItemModal = this.nextElementSibling;
    newItemModal.classList.toggle("hidden");
    var addNewBtn = newItemModal.querySelector("#listItemSave");
    //current board
    var board = this.closest("div.list");
    //current list
    var list = board.querySelector(".todo--items");

    addNewBtn.addEventListener  ("click", function(e) {
      //current board id
      var boardId = board.dataset.boardid;
      //current title
      var title = newItemModal.querySelector("#listTitle");
      var titleValue = title.value;
      //current content
      var content = newItemModal.querySelector("#listTextarea");
      var contentValue = content.value;


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: { content: contentValue , title: titleValue , listid: boardId  },

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $("#todoItems-" + id + "").append(data);

       }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using querySelectorAll on ID selector?

Comment: Every time you execute the event handler attached to `addNewItem` it will *add another event handler* to `addNewBtn`. So, if you click three times `addNewItem` and then click `addNewBtn` once, you'd get three handlers executed for that second click.

Comment: how can you have a foreach of one thing? addnewitems is the ID addNewItem. an ID is one element. (at least it should be)

Comment: @VLAZ so how to make only one evenethandler if I click button several times?

Comment: @BryanDellinger yeah I know. It is ID for now because I had only one board but now I have several boards with this add new modal so I will change that ID to class. Thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable, lets say `busy`, to validate that an AJAX request isn't already on going.

You could set this variable in the `beforeSend` callback of AJAx and then updated it back to false in the `finally` callbac :

```
var addNewItems = document.querySelectorAll("#addNewItem");
var addNewSubmits = document.querySelectorAll("#listItemSave");
addNewItems.forEach(function (addNewItem) {
    addNewItem.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var newItemModal = this.nextElementSibling;
        newItemModal.classList.toggle("hidden");
        var addNewBtn = newItemModal.querySelector("#listItemSave");
        //current board
        var board = this.closest("div.list");
        //current list
        var list = board.querySelector(".todo--items");

        var busy = false;

        addNewBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            //current board id
            var boardId = board.dataset.boardid;
            //current title
            var title = newItemModal.querySelector("#listTitle");
            var titleValue = title.value;
            //current content
            var content = newItemModal.querySelector("#listTextarea");
            var contentValue = content.value;

            if (!busy) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "add.php",
                    beforeSend: () => {
                        busy = true;
                    }
                    data: {
                        content: contentValue,
                        title: titleValue,
                        listid: boardId
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $("#todoItems-" + id + "").append(data);
                    },
                    complete: () => {
                        busy = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is a pretty simple solution but it works.

Comment: for some reasons this solutions doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MartynasTreigys I havn't testing this , there a good chance you can't simply copy and paste it into your code. however, you should try to understand what i did and apply it to you own context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addNewBtn.onclick = function () {}` instead to overlap the previous listener in this case.
But it's not recommended to register listeners inside another listener. Try to move it out of there.